# How to cast Scala value already defined in the function

Tags: scala

how to convert a value when using it? Example:

```
scala> def sum(x:Double, y:Int) {
     | x + y
     | }
sum: (x: Double,y: Int)Unit

scala> println(sum(2,3))
()
```

How to modify the line with println to print the correct number?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that `sum` returns `Unit`:

```
sum: (x: Double,y: Int)Unit
```

This happens because you missed an equal sign between method declaration and body:

```
def sum(x:Double, y:Int) {
```

You should have declared it like this:

```
def sum(x:Double, y:Int) = {
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `()` *is* `Unit`

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is not with casting but with your function definition. Because you ommitted the `=` before the function parameters and the function body, it returns `Unit` (i.e. nothing), as the REPL told you: `sum: (x: Double,y: Int)`**Unit**. Simply add the equals:

```
def sum(x: Double, y: Int) = {
  x + y
}
```

Now your `sum` method will return a `Double`.